# Grout clogging up drain in bathtub

Tags: plumbing

I believe the person (idiot) who remodeled the home I recently purchased let the grout and other construction material he used to rehab the bathroom go down the drain.  I believe it has dried in the pipe and there is only a very small opening for water to drain through.  The house is a slab, so I can't get to the pipe under the tub.  Is there anything I can use to dissolve the grout so that the water will drain faster.  He obviously didn't know what he was doing as the tile is already bulging behind the faucet.

Comment: What makes you think it's grout and not a normal clog (hair, lint, paper, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Powerful Wet/Dry Vac for loose pieces before, if that is not the case, and the Grout is a solid piece, Go to the hardware shop and buy a small bottle of Hydrochloric acid, it’s also called Muriatic acid in some places.

Dilute the acid with water (2 parts water, 1 part muriatic acid) and pour it down your drain. You may need the repeat the process a couple of times still the grout is dissolved and flushed away. 
Make sure you wear eye, skin and breathing protection. Turn the bathroom fan on and open the windows. When you pour it down the drain leave the room straight away and close the door, come back in about 10 minutes and turn the water on the flush the drain. 
If you are not confident doing that get someone else who has had experience with this type of acid. Hydrochloric acid is used a lot on building sites the clean and remove grout. 
What I would try first is get the contractor back to your place and have him do it for you. That’s the least he can do for you. If he won’t come back I’m afraid you will have to do the job.

Comment: Always add acid to water when mixing. Not the other way around.